# Are there any other global networks other than the internet?

Tags: networking, internet, wan

The original question was asked [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15440/global-networks-are-there-any-other-than-the-internet). I am interested in knowing the same. Are there any other global networks other than the internet? Or non-global but on a country-wide scale(ATM network maybe?)

Also, I was reading about Transport layer protocol when this line caught my eye:

> More than one transport layer protocol may be available to network applications. For example, the internet has two protocols - TCP and UDP. Each of these protocols provides a different set of transport layer services to in invoking applications

more specifically this line:
`For example, the internet has two protocols -TCP and UDP`
What are some examples of non-internet Transport layer protocols?

The book briefly talked about `Telephone network` as WAN(Apart from the internet). But that implemented `circuit-switched network`. I doubt that those even had a Transport layer protocol. So, is there any other network that provides `Transport-Layer services`?

PS: I did ask the question on **[server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/744161/are-there-any-global-network-other-than-the-internet?noredirect=1#comment931641_744161)** as directed in the original question to do so, but it was closed as off-topic in the former. At this time, I am not sure on which stack exchange site i should ask this? If it's off-topic for **SuperUser** as well can you please direct me to the specific **StackExchange** site where this will not be?

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Comment: "It is estimated that 80% of the global mobile market uses the GSM standard, present in more than 212 countries and territories. Its ubiquity makes international roaming very common between mobile phone operators, enabling subscribers to use their phones in many parts of the world. In order to achieve this, these networks must be interconnected by way of peering arrangements, and therefore the GSM network is a truly global one."

Comment: @DavidPostill that there are some military networks other than the internet but that still not satisfies the second part of the question. And also are there any **publicly available** network?

Comment: Note that questions asking for **lists of things** are off-topic. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: You can search yourself for "osi model transport layer examples".

Comment: @DavidPostill If you have some reference can you give a link for that? I was unable to find any satisfactory example as all the tropics on Transport layer are surrounded on internet and TCP.

Comment: No I don't. This is an off-topic question. You should **do your own  research**.